# After git clone all files are unversioned | GIT | IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitlab

After cloning repository and performing Gradle refresh. I did  `Enable Version Control Integration`. After that, all files are now un-versioned. How add to my Gitlab credentials in IntelliJ so that it can recognize the local masters code and I can fetch/ checkout remote branches.
Possible solution which I saw in earlier post was

1. To check in `.idea` folder -> `vcs.xml` where the `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY` is set to `vcs` (which it is).
2. To check whether `.gitignore` contains `.idea` (which it does).

[image]

`File`->`Settings`->`VCS`->`GIT`
[image]

Comment: Please share Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Git dialog screenshot and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Try specifying the path to git executable in the IDE settings and click `Test`. What would be the result?

Comment: @CrazyCoder git executable = `http://myrepo.com/project-name/another-project-v2.git` ?

Comment: No, it's the git client binary, likely `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it results into `Git Version is 2.14.2`

Comment: What does `git status` report if you run it in the project root directory? Any exceptions in `idea.log` (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: git status returns

`On branch master`

`No commits yet`

`Changes to be committed:`
  `(use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)`

 `new file:   ../.idea/.gitignore`
 `new file:   ../.idea/compiler.xml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/gradle.xml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/jarRepositories.xml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/mig-v2-master.iml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/misc.xml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/modules.xml`
 `new file:   ../.idea/vcs.xml`

`Untracked files:`
 ` (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)`

 `./`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222804/discussion-between-abhishek-dasgupta-and-crazycoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Response](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252605#focus=Comments-27-4436977.0-0) from JetBrains Support:

Looks like IDE shows the same as git status. You have the entire folder `./` as Untracked, IDE just expands it to the list of files.
They are untracked because you are looking into the git repository in `~/IdeaProjects/mig-v2-master`  which is a fresh one.
The one you cloned is `~/IdeaProjects/mig-v2` and seems like it is not opened in the IDE.

Check the project that is opened and mappings in Settings | Version Control.